# Наследование от объединения (union)

Tags: c++, наследование

Здравствуйте.

Разъясните, пожалуйста, почему нельзя наследоваться от `union`?

```
union Uexample{
    int u1;
    int u2;
};
class Cexample : public Uexample {};
```

Ошибка:

> error C2569: 'Uexample' : enum/union cannot be used as a base class

Хотя наследоваться от структуры возможно.

```
struct Sexample{
    int s1;
    int s2;
};
class Cexample : public Sexample {};
```

Comment: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075643/unions-as-base-class

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615001/why-union-cant-be-used-in-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Структура и клас это почти одно и тоже за исключением того что отличаются доступом (`public / private`) по умолчанию, а вот объединение к ним никак не относится это всего лишь две или более переменных находящиеся в одном адресном пространстве, Вы же не будете делать наследование от обычной переменной.